# sharepoint 2010 webpart obfuscation

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-enterprise

i am trying to obfuscate my custom web part.

first i created my web part using visual studio 2010.
i build the web part it build the web part as .dll in bin folder.
i obfuscated the .dll with confuser obfuscator.
and i replaced the original dll with obfuscated dll.
then i trying to pack the web part.

but visual studio is rebuilding the web part and packing with newly rebuild dll (original )
instead of obfuscated dll.

is there any other way to obfuscate share point 2010 webpart?

Comment: Interesting question. Let me think about it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of rebuilding the project, package it.

Also you can just replace the dlls inside the wsp as if it was a zip file.

Comment: i try to packit but while i said packit the visual studio rebulding itself and pack with rebulded dll insted of my obfuscated dll

Comment: In that case you can use the post-build events to have visual studio obfuscate your dll after building it and before packaging. This will happen automatically so is very comfortable for the developer. 
Liam Clear wrote a tutorial on it:
http://blog.helloitsliam.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=23
Also here's an msdn article on the subject:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh977082(v=vs.107).aspx